# Display href as an image in Google maps info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am importing a json file into google maps to display markers with info windows.  One of the json items is an href to a stored image.  I wish the href to display as an image or link to image button, not as text.  I have attempted to place image tags and html divs inside the  infoWindow.setContent (); as per some answers which did not work.  Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Sample json

```
[
  {
    "lat":"50.90737498194628",
    "lng":"-114.10501346073356",
    "username":"Bill Someone",
    "role":"Incident Commander",
    "text":"Test message with photo attached",
    "image":"https://someimagepostImages%2FdU8vD3evV5mWOpbWRHq",
    "time":"2018/10/23 09:28:02am"
  }
]
```

map.js file

```
function infoBox(map, marker, data) {
     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
             infoWindow.setContent ('<b>name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.username + "<br />" + '<b>role:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.role + "<br />" + '<b>message:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.text + "<br />"  + '<b>time:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.time + "<br />" + '<b>image:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.image);
             infoWindow.open(map, marker);
         });

     (function(marker, data) {
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
         infoWindow.setContent ('<b>name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.username + "<br />" + '<b>role:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.role + "<br />" + '<b>message:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.text + "<br />"  + '<b>time:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.time + "<br />" + '<b>image:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.image);
         infoWindow.open(map, marker);
       });
     })(marker, data);
 }
```

Comment: Is this what you want ? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay

Comment: Or if you want this behavior go to this website and click on the bus icon on the right. Take a look at the image at the left bottom corner of the map. You can let me know which behavior you expect.
http://www.happyvalleygz.com/TranSport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use an `img` tag for that or an `a` tag.

```
infoWindow.setContent ('<b>name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.username + "<br />" +
'<b>role:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.role + "<br />" + '<b>message:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + 
data.text + "<br />"  + '<b>time:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' + data.time + "<br />" + 
'<b>image:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><img src="' + data.image + '" >);
```

You can insert HTML in the infoWindow without major issues. You can also style the elements. I'd recommend you to create a small div with the elements ordered more semantically instead of using `b` tags.

Comment: Thanks, the img tag gives an error of unexpected token, but it has put me on the right direction to solving this.

Comment: You are probably not escaping the characters correctly @ThomasDegroot the unexpected token comes when JavaScript is not receiving the content it's expecting.